# How to create an extension in chrome to run a website

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating a chrome extension to run a web url in the popup . i am referencing these urls [url 1](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)  and [Chrom extension example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) and created like this 
my **mainfest.json** file is

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Protecto",
  "description": "This extension will connect you with protecto application",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://www.url.com"
  ]
}
```

**popup.js** file is

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://www.url.com/User/Login";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**popup.html** is

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 900px;
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="status"> </div>
    <img id="image-result" hidden>
  </body>
</html>
```

it creates an icon on right side .It is opening the current page only in the popup when i click on the icon. But if i click on the links nothing happened. please help if any body knows about this

**UPDATE**

I also tried to include iframe like this

```
<iframe src="url"></iframe>
```

but it stops extension to work.

Comment: Why this approach? Why not simply an `<iframe>`?

Comment: i have tried this also , but not working . it stops all .

Comment: actually my url is https "https://www.protacto.com/User/Login" . i think this is the issue

Comment: The page has the header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` so it will not allow itself to be iframed on a different origin.